# cannot convert null to type "System.Datetime"

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script (not mine) that changes aduser properties. I'm beginner and i don"t understand how to change this file.

Script read a Microsoft SQL for whrite aduser properties.

problem exist because the sql value is null et and in powershell script compare date and want tu put this value to attibute (aduser accountexpirationdate).

I receive error message "cannot convert null to type "System.Datetime""

```
$ZeroDate = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month 1 -Year 1990 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 1
    
If ($Employee.TerminationDate -And $Employee.TerminationDate -Gt $ZeroDate) {
    $doChangeExpiry = $True
    If ($ADUser.AccountExpirationDate) {
        $ts = New-TimeSpan -End $Employee.TerminationDate -Start $ADUser.AccountExpirationDate
        $EndUseAccountDayCount = $ts.Days
        If ($EndUseAccountDayCount -ge 0) {
            $doChangeExpiry = $False
        }
    }
    If ($doChangeExpiry) {
        $isChanged = $True
        $EmployeeChange = [Change]::new()
        $EmployeeChange.Key = 'AccountExpirationDate'
        $EmployeeChange.Employee = $Employee
        $EmployeeChange.NewValue = $Employee.TerminationDate
        $EmployeeChange.OldValue = $ADUser.AccountExpirationDate
        $ChangeLog.Add($EmployeeChange)
    } Else {
        $Employee.TerminationDate = $Null
    }
}
```

Perhaps, i do put nullorempty but i don't know how to whrite that ;)
Can you help me ?

Thks

Comment: this >>> `If ($Employee.TerminationDate -And $Employee.TerminationDate -Gt $ZeroDate)` <<< looks wrong. are you trying to compare BOTH of those dates to the `$ZeroDate` value?  if so, you need to add the test to the 1st part since that is just being tested for non-blank as currently written.

Comment: At which statement is the error thrown? Please post the error message in full if possible

Comment: What is `[Change]::new()` ??

Comment: hello, thls for reply. we changed  $Employee.TerminationDate = $Null by $Employee.TerminationDate = $ZeroDate

$ZeroDate = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month 1 -Year 1990 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 1

Comment: But i don t know how to whrite:
if  $Employee.TerminationDate isnullorempty Clear-ADAccountExpiration
i found how to test a string but not how to test variable contents